# Namespace in swift

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces

Suppose i have a class A having nested class B declared as follows

```
Class A {
    Class B {
    }
}

Class B {
}
```

Now as far as i know, Within class A, i can call class B directly but from outside i will have to call it as A.B .Now if i have also declared a new Class B seperately outside Class A and now i want to call seperate class B from inside class A, how will i call it?

```
Class A {
    Class B {
    }
    let b = B()
}
```

Which instance will constant b hold? Nested class B or seperate class B?

Comment: You can easily test it yourself with `print(String(describing: A().b))`

Answer (score 0):

This will print `AB`, so it uses the one in scope. Which is the behaviour I would expect.

```
class A {
    class B {
        init() {
            print("AB");
        }
    }
    init() {
        let b = B();
    }
}

class B {
    init() {
        print("B");
    }
}

let a = A();
```

http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5808773982d5081939b477e4

This will work but I can't explain why, I was just messing about with the classes. So if anyone can enlighten me feel free.

So I had the idea of passing the outside class B to another variable so I could call that instead and got this to work. To do this I needed to add `required` to the `init()` in the outside be and call `init()` explicitly when instantiating the class. This will print `AB` then `B`.

I wouldn't advise doing this, I'd just rename one of the classes, but it does answer the question of how the class could be called.

**Update:** @MartinR has a better solution in the comments that uses the apps name scope to differentiate between the scoped classes.

```
class B {
    required init() {
        print("B");
    }
}

let otherB = B.self;

class A {
    init() {
        let b = B();
        let theOtherB = otherB.init();
    }
    class B {
        init() {
            print("AB");
        }
    }
}

let a = A();
```

http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58087e5782d5081939b477e8

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of the separate class `B` within the `A` class. Creating the instance of `B` inside `A` will always go to the closest definition of `B`.

Basically, it is a bad practice to have classes with the same name in a project. Of course, there may be exceptions, but still, having two instances of different classes with same name inside another class is confusing even when possible technically.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't, but it *is* possible, with `let b = <ModuleName>.B()`

Comment: Got it. I know it is a bad practice, but i just wanted to get clarified to know the language deeply.

Comment: @MartinR how do you define a module if there is just a project with two classes and no submodules?

Comment: There is a "Product Module Name" setting, and by default it is derived from the application name. You'll see it as the initial component of `print(String(describing: A().b))`.

Comment: @MartinR got it, thanks. Do you mind to edit my answer? Or it's better I delete it?

Comment: @MartinR I think you should post that, it is the correct answer.